# URI scheme in your app's manifest is not set up correctly

Tags: android, schema, manifest, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk

I am trying to connect my Dropbox, i do not know where this problem comes from but I have edited the manifest file well! what am I doing wrong can anyone help me please...

this is my manifest file :

```html
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.JurnalCloudApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".DropboxActivity"
            android:exported="true" />
        <activity
            android:name=".SyncActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
                <data android:scheme="db-is9rikcfjhforcl" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"/>
    </application>
```

And the Error is:

```html
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: URI scheme in your app's manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity with the scheme: db-db-is9rstkcfjhlorcl
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data android:scheme` looks correct. Based on the error message, it looks like you're passing in "db-YOURAPPKEY" to the `startOAuth2PKCE` method [to start the app authorization flow](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-java/blob/master/examples/DropboxAndroid/app/src/main/java/com/dropbox/dropboxexample/MainActivity.kt#L100), when you should just specify the app key only, that is, "YOURAPPKEY" (no "db-").

If you include that "db-" in your app key in your code, the SDK will expect "db-db-is9rstkcfjhlorcl" (with an extra "db-") in your Manifest, which would be incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm i deleted the code of that line (db-), this time I encountered this error:

same error without two -db

```html
URI scheme in your app's manifest is not set up correctly. You should have a com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity with the scheme: db-is9rikcfjhforcl
```

manifest file:

```html
<activity
            android:name="com.dropbox.core.android.AuthActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
                <data android:scheme="is9rikcfjhforcl" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

```html
 Auth.startOAuth2Authentication(this, this.getString(R.string.app_key));
```

and string resource:

```html
 <string name="app_key">is9rikcfjhforcl</string>
```